# C# / Unity Instantiate multiple GameObjects and move their position.x by +1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a code that spawns random amount of coins, but the problem is that they are spawning inside each other.

What i want is to have a line of coins, not just one that has like 3 spawned in it.

I tried to get the current x position of the current object that spawned and added +1 to its x cord, so that the next object spawns +1 to x cord.

```
        private void SpawnCoin()
{
    coinSpawn = Random.Range(1, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < coinSpawn; i++)
    {
        spawnCoin = Instantiate(coin) as GameObject;
        spawnCoin.transform.SetParent(transform);
        float currentPos = spawnCoin.transform.position.x;
        //spawnCoin.transform.Translate(currentPos+1f, -0.1f, -1f);
    }

}
```

I think there must be something with the Parent's transform that changes it back to 0?

Also the coins are moving in the x cordinate:

```
    // Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    transform.Translate(0f, -0.1f, -1f);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    transform.Translate(0f - Time.deltaTime * BackgroundScroll.speed, 0f, 0f);
}
```

Edit: I know that `//spawnCoin.transform.Translate(currentPos+1f, -0.1f, -1f);` this changes the current spawned coins transform, thats why i commented it, but i want to change the upcoming ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
private void SpawnCoin()
{
     coinSpawn = Random.Range(1, 5);
     float x = 1.0f;
     for (int i = 0; i < coinSpawn; i++)
     {
         spawnCoin = Instantiate(coin) as GameObject;
         spawnCoin.transform.SetParent(transform);
         float currentPos = spawnCoin.transform.position.x;
         spawnCoin.transform.Translate(currentPos+x, -0.1f, -1f);
         x+=1.0f;
     }
```

}